# Meson: replicate the include function from CMake?

Tags: meson-build

Currently giving a try at Meson.

I would like to replicate in Meson the `include` function from CMake that I use to import other .cmake files into a file for common definitions. It helps to keep my rules separated, organized, and each CMakeLists.txt are shorter.

Those definitions are in a parent folder that multiple projects can use.

Back to Meson:
I tried import, dependency but my meson.build is never found.
What is the way to make what I am currently doing in CMake happen using Meson?

Answer (score 0):

with subdir('')
called from a meson.build you import the meson build found in the

e.g.

```
projDir---meson.build
       ---src
       ------meso.build
```

Comment: It implies that we have build files that have a sub dependency.. I will give it a try and see if that works out for me

Comment: After digging, I found that machine files https://mesonbuild.com/Machine-files.html#loading-multiple-machine-files are what I need. Willing to leave you the points if you add that part to your answer :)